# React: get input values without using 'onChange'

Tags: reactjs, input, onchange

How can I get input values without using `onChange` to get them to state? The reason being I am using `useEffect` to animate the form upon loading and using `onChange` resets the animation upon every typed letter, which is not desired. I just want to get the input value to state (or to the `submitHandler`, whatever works) when the submit button is clicked.

This is what I am using right now:

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState('')

<input 
type="email" 
className="loginPage-form-item-input" 
name='email' 
value={email} 
onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} 
required
/>

const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(login(email, password))
  }
```

I have tried using `ref` and `useRef` but I don't quite understand them and I get errors like `Function components cannot have string refs`.

**Edit (useEffect code):**

```
const formRef = useRef(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    gsap.from(formRef.current, {duration: 1, y:100, opacity: 0, ease: 'power2.out'})
  })
```

using `ref={formRef}` on form div

Comment: Edited post to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are triggering an animation on `useEffect` and any state update results on that animation being executed again. That means you didn't specify your dependencies properly at `useEffect`.

When you don't specify your dependencies, than it will execute on every rerender. `useEffect` takes a second argument to declare those dependencies. since you want to execute only on mount, you should pass an empty array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // animation code
  }, []) // empty array will execute your animation only on mount
```

[useEffect documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: It works, thanks! I am using gsap for the animation and I removed the dependency because I kept getting a message by the console saying it was an 'unnecessary dependency'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this. But Not recommended way to do things.

```
function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const {username, password } = e.target.elements
    console.log({username: username.value, password: password.value })
}

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
   <input type="text" id="username"/>
   <input type="text" id="password"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Comment: It kinda works but it throws a JSON cirular error...